# rspec find record in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I'm trying to test a controller and I have this:

```
@category ||= Category.where(name: 'cat1').limit(1).first
@product ||= Product.where(...).limit(1).first
```

`Product` haves an attribute called `category_id` from an association one to one: Product has_one Category.

When I run the test, I create the Product object with FactoryGirl and I load the `seeds.rb` just with two caterories.

The result is that `@product.category_id` is not equals to `@category.id`. The id for category is always the same (because it is taken from database or the seeds in this case)

My question is how to improve this?

**UPDATE**

The original factory for product is

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :product do
    name "Some Product"
    ...

    trait :category_1 do
      after(:build) do  |product|
        product.pictures << FactoryGirl.build(:picture, :product => product)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But when I add an association I get the error `can't write unknown attribute 'product_id'`

The new factories are

```
#factory for product
...
trait :category_1 do
    category { create(:category) }
    after(:build) do  |product|
        product.pictures << FactoryGirl.build(:picture, :product => product)
    end
end
...

#factory for category
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :category do
        name "category1"
    end
end
```

Comment: Can you post that factorygirl code too?

Comment: Use `to_s` function with id.

Comment: You are saying the relationship is "Product has_one Category" but by using `@product.category_id` sounds like "Category has_one Product", can you clarify this ?

Comment: Yes, Product has one Category. The category table haves just 2 attributes (id and name). In `Product` there is a attribute with this relation (category_id)

Comment: Well, it should be "Product belongs_to Category" then if the `category_id` attribute is on Product.

Comment: @ChrisPeters OK, you are right, it was my mistake. But this not solve the original problem

Comment: I've made mistakes like that in the past, so I could have potentially helped you by pointing it out. Can you explain in your question what you're doing in your `seeds.rb` file? That doesn't seem quite right to me. In my opinion, you should keep all record generation in factories. My guess is that you're creating categories both in your factories and in your seeds. What happens if you put this line just above the assertion that fails in your test? `puts Category.all.to_yaml` Also, can you provide a full example of a test that's failing so we can see what you're trying to do.

Comment: @ChrisPeters some minutes before I read your comment I did exactly what you wrote. The problem was that the category was taken from the seeds. The solution is create a product by factory: `@product = FactoryGirl.new ...` and take the category from this product: `@category = @product.category` now I'm ensuring that both id's are the same.

Comment: Very nice. Glad you got it sorted out.